# what kind of type resistor do I need in PTH05050W?

Tags: power-supply, power, dc-dc-converter, virtex-series-fpga

I found what I need to apply my xilinx virtex5 FPGA board,
PTH05050W 6-A, 5-V INPUT NON-ISOLATED WIDE OUTPUT ADJUST POWER MODULE at www.ti.com.

Maybe, this need to change by resistor to set output voltage.
But there's not any information about what kind of resistor type I need it.

Would you please help me what kind of type resistor do I need to set the voltage level.

My question is not about resistor charicteristic. I can read this form the PDF. My question is the type what type of SMT resistor or ceramic resistor or something else.

## update

I'd like to change the resistor in http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pth05050w.pdf
But I found so many type resistors as bwlows.

1005(1%) 1005(5%) 1005 1608(0.1%)
1608(1%) 1608(5%) 1608 2012(0.1%)
2012(1%) 2012(5%) 2012 3216(5%)
3216 3225 5025 5025..

I don't know what kind of type resistor I need it.
Would you help any hint?

Comment: Rset is shown as a 1%, 0.1W type with values between 698 and 36k5 according to the chart on page 3 of the pdf  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pth05050w.pdf

Comment: You couldn't even be bothered to proofread the title!  If you don't take your problem seriously, then there's no reason we should either. *Screw this*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [datasheet, page 6](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pth05050w.pdf), which is always a good reading. The requirements for the \$  R_{SET} \$ are:

- Power rating 0.05 W
- Tolerance 1%
- Temperature stability 100ppm/°C

[image]

Also there information about the correct placement too.

Comment: I'd like to change the resistor in http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pth05050w.pdf But I found so many type resistors as bwlows.

1005(1%) 1005(5%) 1005 1608(0.1%) 1608(1%) 1608(5%) 1608 2012(0.1%) 2012(1%) 2012(5%) 2012 3216(5%) 3216 3225 5025 5025..

I don't know what kind of type resistor I need it. Would you help any hint?

Comment: If you are going to solder the resistor by hand then 2012(1%) will be good. Also these numbers are the metric size of the resistors in inches, so a 2012 is 2.0 x 1.25 inch a 3216 is 3.2 x 1.6 inch, and so on. [Recommended reading](http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-sizes-and-packages/).

Comment: How about 1608 by hand?

Comment: If you are not  experienced in soldering, I do not recommend.